# Kick user session out from own controller action method serverside

Tags: identityserver3

In IdentityServer3 do we have any extension method like owincontext.Environment.logoutCurrentSession for the logged in user. We have our own custom login pages and logout page and we already have our own logout page where we used to logout the existing user through context.Authentication.Signout stuff.

Answer (score 1):

In Identity Server you need to call LogoutEndPoint with user IdentityToken for logout user and end of session. Also you must cleanup to cookie with SignoutCleanup. I think, first you need to read [documentation](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2) of Identity Server 3.

[Logout EndPoint Usage](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/endpoints/endSession.html)